# Click on open JavaFX Menu embedded in JFXPanel does not close it

Tags: javafx, menu, jfxpanel

When embedding a Menu in a Swing window through a [`JFXPanel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html), I cannot close the menu by clicking on it. Sometimes it blinks, as if it closed and immediately reopened.

```java
package testjavafx;

public class TestMenuJavaFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(
                new Menu("Menu 1", null,
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 1-1"),
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 1-2")),
                new Menu("Menu 2", null,
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 2-1"),
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 2-2")),
                new Menu("Menu 3", null,
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 3-1"),
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 3-1")));
        menuBar.setPrefWidth(300);
        Region root = new Pane(menuBar);
        root.setPrefSize(300, 185);

        useJFXPanel(root);
        //usePrimaryStage(primaryStage, root);
    }

    private static void useJFXPanel(Region root) {
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(root));
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("test menu JavaFX");
        jFrame.setSize((int) root.getWidth(), (int) root.getHeight());
        jFrame.add(jfxPanel);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void usePrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage, Parent root) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(TestMenuJavaFX.class, args);
    }
}
```

By using the method `usePrimaryStage` I get the expected behavior (click on the menu to open it, click again to close it), but with `useJFXPanel` the problem appears.

This is an event handling issue, the mouse click is first dispatched to the JFXPanel as a Swing mouse event then the `JFXPanel` internally dispatches a JavaFX mouse event to its embedded `Scene`.
It appears that, during the Swing part, the menu loses focus and closes, and when the event reaches the Menu instance it finds it closed and therefore opens it.

I tried to inherit the `Menu` class to add a mouse click event handler to it, however it does not handle mouse clicks, and using the showing/shown and hiding/hidden events provided did not help it (because the problem happens earlier).
I also tried to subclass `MenuBar` to add a mouse click event handler, but the handler is only called when clicking on the bar outside of a menu, so no luck here, and to subclass `JFXPanel` to override `processMouseEvent` and retrieve the `MenuBarButton` instance through reflection black magic but i couldn't make it work.

This is a bug, right? And is there a (easy and clean, ideally) workaround to this issue?

I'm using OpenJDK 11.0.10.9 and JavaFX 17.0.0.1.

Comment: I also could not find any info about this issue, nor a bug report already filed on the JavaFX tracker (I know, this is a niche use case)

Comment: You should only create and show a `JFrame` on the AWT event dispatch thread, not on the JavaFX Application Thread. I don't know if that will fix your problem, but you should post code that follows the threading rules for both UI toolkits.

Comment: You're right. This is just an example of course, not actual production code. I wrote it quickly, perhaps a bit too quickly and did not bother with proper set up since this way seems to work fine.

Comment: For reference, i submitted the bug JDK-9072478.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system, this wouldn't run, but hung on startup because the `JFrame` is created and shown on the wrong thread. Correcting that did display the behavior you describe, which does appear to be a bug.

I found one workaround, which is to capture a `ON_HIDING` event and schedule a call to hide the menu further down the event queue, using `Platform.runLater(...)`. The resulting code looks like;

```
public class TestMenuJavaFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(
                new Menu("Menu 1", null,
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 1-1"),
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 1-2")),
                new Menu("Menu 2", null,
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 2-1"),
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 2-2")),
                new Menu("Menu 3", null,
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 3-1"),
                        new MenuItem("Menu item 3-1")));
        menuBar.setPrefWidth(300);
        
        menuBar.getMenus().forEach(menu -> {
            menu.addEventHandler(Menu.ON_HIDING, e -> {
                Platform.runLater(menu::hide);
            });
        });
        
        Region root = new Pane(menuBar);
        root.setPrefSize(300, 185);

        useJFXPanel(root);
        //usePrimaryStage(primaryStage, root);
    }

    private static void useJFXPanel(Region root) {
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(root));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("test menu JavaFX");
            jFrame.setSize((int) root.getWidth(), (int) root.getHeight());
            jFrame.add(jfxPanel);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static void usePrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage, Parent root) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(TestMenuJavaFX.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed that there was a literally five lines long solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @joH1 It's still a bit of a hack...